# Is the concept of Deferred Buffers used anywhere outside ODBC?

Tags: c++, odbc, deferred-buffer

In ODBC, [Deferred Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a concept where a value is used at some time after it is specified in a function call.

As part of my research I was trying to figure out, if there is any other application currently being employed where Deferred Buffers are used outside ODBC?

In this regard I would like to know from the community if they have encounter something similar in other areas.

Answer (score 7):

It is a very specific implementation detail of ODBC.  Which dates from the stone age, in the early 1990s 16-bit operating systems like Windows 3.x were common.  Which put a heavy premium on memory usage and avoiding storage duplication was very important.

So the common pattern in ODBC was for the app to allocate the storage needed for table data and queries.  Those "deferred buffers" you are talking about.  SQLBindCol() permits the ODBC driver to, later, poke the retrieved data directly into the storage allocated by the app.  SQLBindParameter() does the opposite for data flowing from the app to the dbase.

It was a brittle scheme, clearly Very Bad Things happen when the app releases the buffers too early.  Which is why modern 32-bit and 64-bit data providers don't do this anymore.  They allocate buffers themselves, the app copies data from/to them.

As a "concept" that applies to other usages, there's nothing that special about it.  Many api functions work that way, you pass a pointer to a buffer and the api function then copies data to/from the buffer you pass.  The only thing that's a bit special about ODBC is that the buffer can stay in use beyond a single api function call.  That's normally better dealt with with the "handle" concept.  In other words, there's an api function that allocates and returns an opaque number to identify the resource.  The app then calls other api functions and passes the handle back.  And one dedicated function that releases the handle again.  Less accidents that way, other than the risk of leaking the handle.

Comment: "The only thing that's a bit special about ODBC is that the buffer can stay in use beyond a single api function call." and that was the part I was interested in.

Comment: I have no idea what else you want me to tell you.  That this scheme is brittle, as pointed out, is a pretty good reason to not use it.  I've debugged ODBC code failing like this (MFC likes it) and it was **no** joy, heap corruption is one of the nastiest bugs to solve.  I gave you a better alternative.